# ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() or read from stream?

Tags: java, android, stream

In my Android app I have data stored in `ByteArrayOutputStream` (for now it's about 1 MB maximum) and I want to pass it to `DataOutputStream`.

The most obvious way is of course calling:

```
dataOS.write(byteArrayOS.toByteArray())
```

but on there is also a more complicated (but maybe more efficient) way of doing:

```
ByteArrayInputStream rdr = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOS.toByteArray());
int read;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((read = rdr.read(buffer)) > 0){
    dataOS.write(buffer,0,read);
}
```

In future the amount of data stored in `ByteArrayOutputStream` might grow. Which one of these two is more efficient? Writing a big chunk of data at once or writing it sequentially?

**UPDATE:**

The `DataOutputStream` is used for writing over network (it's created over `UrlConnection.getOutputStream()` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is more efficient, since instead of creating N chunks of 1024 bytes and sending them separately to the DataOutputStream, it sends the whole byte array at once.

You already have the whole byte array in memory anyway. What could be useful is to read and write in chunks from a stream that does not read from an in-memory byte array (like a File or Socket Input stream), because that would avoid having the whole byte array in memory.

Comment: I understand. I forgot to mention that the `DataOutputStream` is used to write over network. Does this make any change?

Comment: Nice explanation JB,will the same apply to a file when I'm reading a file through a  `servlet (request)` ??,Then the second approach is better ??

Comment: @NumberFour: not, it doesn't. Reading in small chunks is useful to avoid consuming too much memory. But here, the data that you read is already in memory.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: You're always forced to use a loop to read from a stream, because you never have a guarantee that everything can be read at once. But the size of the buffer depends on how much memory you're ready to consume. If you read by chunks of 10MBs and have 100 concurrent requests, each reading from a file, that will consume 1GB of memory. If you read by chunks of 1KB and have 100 concurrent requests, it will consume only 100KB, and won't be significantly slower.

Answer (score 1):

As a thumbrule, using buffers with `streams` is `preferable`. The reason is, direct `filesystem`(bottle neck resource) accesses are costly and slow. That said, `streams` are usually chained and as long as the `stream` at the end(directly accessing the `filesystem`) is not `reading/writing`, unit by unit you are fine.

*Edit*
In your case, there is not much difference but the one which writes bigger *chunk* will be *slightly* faster.

Comment: I'd like to see your explanation of why the buffer-based solution is faster.

Comment: reading one element at a time from a contiguous memory, the buffer, takes more operations than reading a chunk at a time.

Comment: That's precisely why the buffer-based solution is slower, and not faster: it takes more operations to create a ByteArrayInputStream and read/write many chunks of the original byte array in a loop than to simply write the whole byte array in a single operation.

Comment: While writing the answer, I mislead myself into thinking that first case was one byte at time and second was the buffer. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

63 lines of code that accelerated my application:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class CustomByteArrayOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    protected byte[] buf;
    protected int count;

    public CustomByteArrayOutputStream() {
        buf = new byte[32];
    }

    public CustomByteArrayOutputStream(int size) {
        if (size >= 0)
            buf = new byte[size];
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("size < 0");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return buf;
    }

    private void expand(int i) {
        if (count + i <= buf.length)
            return;
        byte[] newbuf = new byte[(count + i) * 2];
        if (buf.length > 0)
            System.arraycopy(buf, 0, newbuf, 0, count);
        buf = newbuf;
    }

    public synchronized void reset() {
        count = 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(int oneByte) {
        if (count == buf.length)
            expand(1);
        buf[count++] = (byte) oneByte;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int len) {
        if (len == 0)
            return;
        expand(len);
        System.arraycopy(buffer, offset, buf, count, len);
        count += len;
    }
}
```

If the size is not known exactly, do this: new CustomByteArrayOutputStream(0);
This will not create anything, and the size will automatically increase when it is first written.

getData() - get data without copying it, but do not forget that you should always get the size of the data when you get it.